# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

i am having an issue while im doing a project in Secure Shell. Im getting the above error even though the table im trying to insert into is empty.
my work includes:

```
CREATE TABLE LARGE_SLIP( 
        MARINA_NUM CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
        SLIP_NUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
        RENTAL_FEE DECIMAL(8,2), 
        BOAT_NAME CHAR(50), 
        OWNER_NUM CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO LARGE_SLIP (
    SELECT MARINA_NUM, SLIP_NUM, RENTAL_FEE, BOAT_NAME, OWNER_NUM 
    FROM MARINA_SLIP WHERE LENGTH = '40');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I tried looking up an answer but most results say that something has been assigned in the table that im trying to insert to. Yet the table is empty. Im still learning and this is actually for a class homework. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The error means that the `SELECT` query is returning multiple rows with `MARINA_NUM = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the sub query on its own, do you get dupe MARINA_NUM values?

```
SELECT MARINA_NUM, SLIP_NUM, RENTAL_FEE, BOAT_NAME, OWNER_NUM 
FROM MARINA_SLIP WHERE LENGTH = '40';
```

If the entire row is duplicated you can use UNIQUE. If not, you'll need to find another way to limit the rows with dupe MARINA_NUM values.

Comment: It shows Marina_num does have replicated 1's but they are in different rows i.e. 

Marina Num( 1,1,1) Slip Num(A1,A2,A3) Rental Fee(3800, 3800, 3600) Boat Name(Anderson II, Our Toy, Escape) Owner Num(AN75, EL25,KE22)

Comment: That's the reason for the error then. Could you post up some sample data and an example of what you'd like the new dataset to look like?

Comment: It should look like the table at the bottom but only where length = 40.[link](http://i.imgur.com/TJ5jXeR.png)       And if youd like to see the actual question in context this is the page im looking at [link](http://i.imgur.com/CQa5b.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was
When you create the table for this problem you actually create 2 primary key's

CREATE TABLE LARGE_SLIP( 
        MARINA_NUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
        SLIP_NUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL, 
        RENTAL_FEE DECIMAL(8,2), 
        BOAT_NAME CHAR(50), 
        OWNER_NUM CHAR(4), PRIMARY KEY(MARINA_NUM, SLIP_NUM));